# Joining two tables in MYSQL with a one to many relationship, but displaying only one entry from the second table

Tags: mysql

If I have two tables, Consumer, and Appointment, would there be a way join them, so that it only displays the most recent appointment? I was able to do it with sql server, but mysql seems to be a bit different.

I would have thought the query to do it would be

```
SELECT Con.ConsumerID, 
       Con.ConsumerName,
       App.AppointmentID, 
       App.ScheduledDate, 
       App.Location 
FROM Consumer Con 
LEFT JOIN Appointment AS App 
  ON Con.ConsumerID = (SELECT ConsumerID 
                       FROM Appointment AS App2 
                       WHERE App2.ConsumerID = Con.ComsumerID 
                       ORDER BY ScheduledDate 
                       DESC 
                       LIMIT 1)
```

That seems to return all the Consumers with all the appointments, so that I have a lot of duplicated Consumers though.

My tables look like

- Consumer

  - ConsumerID
  - ConsumerName
- Appointment

  - AppointmentID
  - ConsumerID
  - ScheduledDate
  - Location

Answer (score 0):

Use this query below.

```
SELECT Consumer.ConsumerName FROM Consumer WHERE Consumer.ConsumerID=(SELECT Appointment.AppointmentID FROM Appointment ORDER BY Appointment.ScheduledDate DESC LIMIT 1)
```

In order to retreive all the data from both tables you can have the query above inside a select from Appointment.

```
SELECT * FROM Appointment where ConsumerID=(SELECT Consumer.ConsumerID FROM Consumer WHERE Consumer.ConsumerID=(SELECT Appointment.AppointmentID FROM Appointment ORDER BY Appointment.ScheduledDate DESC LIMIT 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I was overthinking it.

```
SELECT
                        Con.ConsumerID,
                        Con.ConsumerName
                        App.AppointmentID,
                        App.ScheduledDate,
                        App.Location
                    FROM
                        Consumer Con
                    LEFT JOIN Appointment AS App
                    ON App.AppointmentID = (
                    SELECT AppointmentID
                    FROM Appointment AS App2
                    WHERE App2.ConsumerID = Con.ConsumerID
                    ORDER BY ScheduledDate DESC LIMIT 1);
```